# How to import Openzep ERC20: Identifier not found

Tags: solidity, erc-20, inheritance, import

Can I get someone's perspective on why I'm unable to find the ERC20 contract I've `npm install @openzeppelin/contracts`.

After `import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";` I get a flag when trying to inherit from `ERC20`

Please see attached photo. I've tried without `node-modules` and without `/`before the `@`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to inherit  `ERC20` yet you have imported  `IERC20.sol`

Answer (score 0):

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20 {
constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") {}
}

Use This above code...

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol" will only import the interface for the ERC20...